# How to call method "<=>"?

Tags: ruby, class, struct

**How to call method "<=>"?**
**The task of the book. I know it can be so "<=>." I need to call the method**

```
Point = Struct.new(:x, :y)

class Point
  def add!(other)
    self.x += other.x
    self.y += other.y
    self
  end

  include Comparable
  def <=>(other)
    return nil unless other.instance_of? Point
    self.x**2 + self.y**2 <=> other.x**2 + other.y**2
  end
end
```

**I created two objects.**

```
p, q = Point.new(1, 0), Point.new(0, 1)
```

Comment: Can't you just use `p <=> q`?

Comment: @NateW  The task of the book. I know it can be so "<=>." I need to call the method

Comment: maybe you can use the 'send' method of any ruby object. This method calls another method that you pass as a symbol, and the following arguments are the parameters of this call. `p.send(:"<=>", q)`  ?

Comment: @jturolla No need for quotes. Ruby parses `:<=>` just fine.

Comment: nice thanks for the tip.

Comment: That's right, I understand. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ruby, operators like `==`, `+` and `<=>` are just methods. You can call the `<=>` method like any other if you want:

```
class Foo
  def <=>(other)
    puts "Comparing #{inspect} to #{other.inspect}!"
    1
  end
end

obj = Foo.new
obj.<=>(9000)
# -> Comparing #<Foo:0x007fef1094b180> to 9000!"
# => 1
```

...but to keep us all from going insane, Ruby gives us *syntactic sugar* that lets us call the method using *infix* notation:

```
obj <=> 9000
# -> Comparing #<Foo:0x007fef1094b180> to 9000!"
# => 1
```

These two forms are equivalent. They are two different ways of calling the `<=>` method.

Of course, when we say "calling the `<=>` method" on `obj` we really mean "sending the message `<=>` to `obj`." Another way to do that is with `send`, or its safer sibling `public_send`:

```
obj.public_send(:<=>, 9000)
# -> Comparing #<Foo:0x007fef1094b180> to 9000!"
# => 1
```

I only point out the above for demonstration's sake. Don't do that in real code. Just call the method using its infix form:

```
p <=> q
```

Answer (score 0):

**The correct method call. Specifically for this example.**

```
p.<=>(q)
```

Comment: Both `a <=> b` and `a.<=>(b)` are syntactically correct. Why do you pretend the formal syntax to be the correct one?

Comment: @SimoneCarletti I know that both answers are correct. But in this case it is a method call

Comment: That's incorrect. Even `[]=` or `==` in Ruby are methods, but I don't think you write `a.==(b)` in your code.

Comment: I study. And I do not know how to call the method. But now I understand everything. Sorry for the incorrect question.